# Adding a record to Address book

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abrecordref

How can I add a new record to address book without using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an addRecord message that you could use, look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ABAddressBook)

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention in my question , that I was looking an answer for iOS , not MacOS. The method addRecord is for MacOS

Comment: In which case, question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726574/iphone-insert-contact-to-address-book-without-any-user-interface