# store contact data which is already available into iphone AddressBook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am developing an apps where i am getting some information regarding contacts example

```
Name:xyz 
Phone number:1234556677
```

So how do i store this information directly into addressBook of an iphone.

NOTE:I dont want the page to navigate to address book and add manually.What i need is i have already have information available like name and phone number. i have a button, click on  button directly it should be stored into address book.

i am stuck in this from past couple of days can anyone help me in solving this.
I have gone though many links but all those take me to add contact.What i really need is to store the information which is already available to me into addressbook.

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726574/iphone-insert-contact-to-address-book-without-any-user-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iPhone : Insert Contact to Address book without any User Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726574/iphone-insert-contact-to-address-book-without-any-user-interface)

This is another user having the same problem.. found this within 1 minute (third link if you google for "iOS add contact")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial which might be helpful to you.

http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/iphone-programming-adding-a-contact-to-the-iphone-address-book/